# C# textFieldParser error

Tags: c#, excel, csv, textfieldparser

I have the following code segment to read a csv file. I am having issues with reading lines that are not really standard. For example a line  like

```
105,"XXX Bank Azerbaijan" CJSC,1078      ,AZ,Baku,"xxx street",Nasimi district
```

goes into catch field since the second field "XXX Bank Azerbaijan" CJSC has quotes not right next to the commas. However when I open this file in Excel, it does not have any problem and separates the fields correctly as:

```
105|XXX Bank Azerbaijan CJSC|1078|AZ|Baku|xxx street|Nasimi district
```

where I used `|` as column separator. Is there a way to have the same effect using `TextFieldParser`, else I will need to use a different csv reader.

```
  using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(fileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")))
  {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
            parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            parser.ReadLine(); // Reads dummy header

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] fieldRow = parser.ReadFields();
                    T fieldsClass = new T();
                    fieldsClass.Initialize(fieldRow);
                    data.Add(fieldsClass);
                    rowCount++;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Skipping line" + parser.ErrorLine);
                }

            }
}
```

Comment: "Fails to read" meaning an exception, or includes quotes which you don't want o include, skips the line?

Comment: Edited fails to read as goes into catch field

Comment: I think your parser will already fail to parse comma's in a string. The expected behavior of `"Foo,Bar"` is probably not `"Foo|Bar"`?

Comment: He doesn't have any comma's in strings and textfieldparser handles comma's within strings just fine through HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes

Comment: Best thing to do is to send the file back and get the programmer to fix the bug in his code.  The only other thing you can do is fix the string yourself before you let the parser see it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if this is actually incorrectly formatted data, then your best bet would be to do what Hans Passant suggested and:

> Best thing to do is to send the file back and get the programmer to
>   fix the bug in his code. The only other thing you can do is fix the
>   string yourself before you let the parser see it.

However, if this is correctly formatted as per whatever specifications were agreed upon way back when, then you can try setting parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;  This will get it to parse BUT it won't strip out the double quotes like in your sample excel import. It will also cause textfieldparser to parse "foo,bar" as '"foo' and 'bar"' instead of "foo,bar" (one field). This may be able to be worked around by specifying a different delimiter to be used by the source of the data, one that won't be found in the middle of field values.

It may be easier to change the specifications to use | as a field delimiter instead of , and deal with the double quotes in each field compared to changing the specifications to only allow double quotes immediately before and after a field delimiter.

Comment: Excel opens this file and separates correctly though, thus it is not incorrectly formatted according to excel.

Comment: It doesn't matter if excel can open it or not. If the format matches what was agreed upon prior to starting this project, then it is correctly formatted. If it doesn't then it isn't.     Unfortunately, as far as I know TextFieldParser doesn't handle this the way you would expect it to. If you want to use TextFieldParser you need to format the data in a way it can read it OR make your own parser.  If you know that no text field will contain commas, you can simply disable HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes .